# Changing the color of multiple buttons

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

**Goal:** Within a set of buttons, when one is pressed, the all of the buttons colors are reset to its default color, while the button that was pressed changes color. (so there will only be one button with a different color)

setup .py file

```
class Profiles(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Profiles, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_profs, -1)

    def create_profs(self, *args):

        #create buttons and screens for each item in acc_abr
        for i in acc_abr:

            #AccountOne inherits from kivy's Screen class. Store new screen into a screen manager named "am"
            self.ids["am"].add_widget(AccountOne(name=i))

            #AccButt inherits from kivy's Button class
            self.ids["acc_butt_box"].add_widget(AccButt(text=i, id=i, on_press=partial(self.switching_function, i)))

    #change current screen 
    def switching_function(self, screename, *args):
        self.ids["am"].current = screename
```

The buttons are created within a for loop, and given an id based on the items in `acc_abr`

What I need to work on is the contents of `AccButt` which looks like:

```
class AccButt(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(on_press = self.change_butt_color)

    def change_butt_color(self, *args):
        self.background_color = 0,0,0,0
```

First of all, I have access to all the buttons id name since its ids are based on the `acc_abr` list.

So my first idea was to create a for loop that changed all the buttons color to its default before changing it's selfs color. which looks like this:

```
def change_butt_color(self, *args):
    for butts in acc_abr:
        self.parent.ids[butts].background_color = 1,1,1,1
    self.background_color = 0,0,0,0
```

The problem is, I'm getting a key error for whatever is in `butts`. So I'm having a communication issue with the buttons.

I'm probably getting the wrong path as to where the other buttons are, or I did not properly assign an id to the Buttons (`AccButt`) or timing is messing things up.

Comment: Try debugging using `print(self.ids)`, `print(self.parent.ids)`, `print(self.parent.parent.ids)` etc to get a better view of where all of your widgets with ids are in relation to each other.

Comment: once again, thanks for your response @Erik. I did `print(self.parent.children)` it shows that all the buttons does exist. but when i do `print(self.parent.children.ids)`, i get an ` AttributeError: 'ObservableList' object has no attribute 'ids'` error. Im sure that the buttons have an id.

Comment: and when I do `print(self.parent.ids)`, it prints `{}`. The parent does in fact have an id which was set in the .kv file.

Comment: Oh, I believe that you can't *set* ids to widgets in python code -- that's only in kv. Maybe try adding your buttons to a list like `self.all_buttons = [btn1, btn2]`. Then do `for butt in self.all_buttons: butt.background_color = 1,1,1,1`

Comment: @Erik you're awesome!!!! this opened me to the lines of `for child in self.parent.children` then `children.background_color`. which works. thanks again!!!!

Comment: Good work! Post your solution as your answer so people know it's been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The path that contains the buttons siblings is `self.parent.children`. With this information, you can change the `background_color` of all the buttons.

**EXAMPLE**

```
def change_butt_color(self, *args):
    for child in self.parent.children:
        child.background_color = 1,1,1,1
    self.background_color = 0,0,0,0
```

notice how the buttons aren't being searched for by `ids`. Instead, `self.parent.children` is used to find the button's parents children, which is, its self of course and the siblings of its self (`self`).

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Use `on_touch_down`, reset `background_color`, and check for `collide_point`

[**Widget Touch Event » on_touch_down**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.on_touch_down)

> on_touch_down(touch)
>
> Receive a touch down event.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   *touch:* [MotionEvent](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent) class
>
> Touch received. The touch is in parent coordinates. See
>   [relativelayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#module-kivy.uix.relativelayout) for a discussion on coordinate systems.
>
> **Returns:**   bool If True, the dispatching of the touch event will stop. If False, the event will continue to be dispatched to the rest
>   of the widget tree.

**[Input Management » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)**

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> ...
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

**[Widget touch event bubbling](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-touch-event-bubbling)**

> When you catch touch events between multiple widgets, you often need
>   to be aware of the order in which these events are propagated. In
>   Kivy, events bubble up from the first child upwards through the other
>   children. If a widget has children, the event is passed through its
>   children before being passed on to the widget after it.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CreateButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if set(self.background_color) & set([0, 0, 0, 0]) == {0}:
            self.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # default texture is grey

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.background_color = [0, 0, 0, 0]    # black color


class OnTouchDownDemo(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OnTouchDownDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build_board()

    def build_board(self):
        # make 9 buttons in a grid
        for i in range(0, 9):
            button = CreateButton(id=str(i))
            self.add_widget(button)


Builder.load_file('main1.kv')


class OnTouchDownApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return OnTouchDownDemo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    OnTouchDownApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<CreateButton>:
    font_size: 50

<OnTouchDownDemo>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 3
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 150
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 150
    padding: [10]
    spacing: [10]
```

## Output

[image: Kivy on_touch_down & collide_point]